# Check through all images in userform

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check through all images in my userform and check values in certain cells in worksheet. Then based on the value, change picture of image object to one of 19 (i1 to i19).

To not check each image I want to loop that process. All image objects have names from slot_1 to slot_42.

Is what I have down here ( slot(a) ) even possible?

Edited: I changed what u said but error still occurs.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
name = Sheets("Player Data").Cells(2, 1).Value
inventory.Caption = name & "' s inventory"
name_label_inv.Caption = name
item_info_label.Visible = False
item_info_label.Caption = " "
Dim a
For a = 1 To 42 Step 1
If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, 11).Value = 0 Then
   Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\empty_icon.jpg")
Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 1 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_exp_book.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 2 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_silver_coin.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 3 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_gold_ingot.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 4 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_heal_hp_1.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 5 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_heal_mp_1.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 6 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_heal_hp_2.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 7 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_weapon_1.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 8 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_weapon_2.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 9 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_weapon_3.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 10 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_arrow.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 11 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_weapon_4.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 12 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_weapon_5.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 13 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_shield_1.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 14 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_armor_helmet_1.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 15 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_armor_chest_1.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 16 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_armor_ring_1.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 17 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_wild_1.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 18 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_wild_2.jpg")
        Else
        If Sheets("Player Data").Cells(a + 1, l2).Value = 19 Then
        Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\The Game\items\item_key.jpg")
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
        End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Me.Controls("slot_" & a).Picture =....`

Comment: Run time error '1004'

Comment: Please sahre the exact line on which the error is happening?

Comment: Posted an answer to explain how it works. you may have to refresh the page to see it...

Comment: I answered myself so u can see curent code

Comment: Please do not post it as an answer. Update your question with the code and also show which line is getting the error

Comment: so excel don't highlight any line

Comment: eddited btw.....

Comment: It must be highlighting Userform1.show. Step thorough the code and then check which line is giving the error

Comment: what about sending u file somehow ?

Comment: Siddharth Rout. I figured that out, but thanks u for help. Without u i would be stack like a week maybe. :*

Comment: if want to see code just ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Me.Controls` to access the control in such a scenario. For example, in your case if the name of the image control is `slot_1` then

```
slot_(a).Picture = LoadPicture(i5)
```

can be written as

```
Me.Controls("Slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture(i5)
```

Here is an example

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As Long
    a = 1
    Me.Controls("Slot_" & a).Picture = LoadPicture("C:\Sample.bmp")
End Sub
```

[image]